# How does a website know the client is not a browser given that --user-agent is provided?

Tags: browser, httprequest, wget, user-agent

I got the following error code when I accessed this website. But a browser can access the website without a problem. How does the website know the client is not a browser given that `--user-agent` is been provided? What additional information need to provided in the request so that website will consider the request is from a regular browser?

```
$ wget --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' -qO- -o /dev/null https://www.genecards.org
$ echo $?
8
```

Comment: Some sites set and check for cookies

Comment: Could you take a look at the website to see specifically what they do and how to overcome their checks?

Comment: Sure, what's your address so I can send you my bill